# How to know struct size casted to void pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, sizeof, void

In my code, there are 2 types that refer a struct:
*TypeX* and *typeX*.

*TypeX* is a void pointer, and *typeX* is the struct type.
After allocating memory to a typeX variable, I passed it (casted) to a TypeX variable (or a void pointer).

I want to get the size of following struct casted to void pointer:

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct _typeX {  
    double a;  
    double b;  
};  

typedef struct _typeX typeX;
typedef void* TypeX;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {  
    TypeX t = NULL;  
    typeX *t0 = NULL;

    t0 = (typeX *) calloc(1, sizeof(typeX));

    t0->a = 123;
    t0->b = 456;

    t = (TypeX) t0;

    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(*t0));
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(*t));

    free(t);

    return 0;  
}
```

But struct size and void pointer size are different:

**Output**

```
16
1
```

Is there any way to identify the struct size correctly by passing a void pointer as parameter?

Comment: `sizeof(*t)` -- is not valid in C when `t` is of type `void*`. Your compiler might be allowing it as an extension. To answer your question, there is no way of knowing the original size from a `void*` ptr. You need to pass it along in a separate variable or cast to appropriate type and use `sizeof`.

Comment: `sizeof(void)` is 1 for gcc, but undefined in the standard. As soon as you cast to void, you lose the type info. C++ has type information hidden and you can use `dynamic_cast` to try to guess which type is behind `void`. You can implement it manually with "custom" structures in C.

Comment: curious what is motivating this question ...

Comment: I don't see any casts to void in the given code.  Or any structs passed into a function.  So what are you trying to show us with the code?

Comment: A void pointer *by definition* is a pointer to something unknown, so no, it is no longer possible to know the size of what it points to. It's your job to keep track of that by other means.

Comment: Having `typeX` and `TypeX` be two completely different things is really being deliberately difficult and obtuse.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons There is a cast to `TypeX`, which is `void*`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah, that got lost in the mix for me.  `typeX` and `TypeX`. :/

Comment: Note: To print `size_t`, use `"%zu"` --> `printf("%zu\n", sizeof *t);`.  With `%lu`, you are (un)lucky.

Comment: "Is there any way to identify the struct size correctly by passing a void pointer as parameter?" --> No.

Comment: @MFisherKDX Not related to this question but a user defined version of struct is generally `void *` perhaps that might trigger folks to know the size as there is no compiler intervention to align the memory (with bit padding).

Comment: Thank you, guys! I have many custom structs that are void pointers in my code, specifically 2 structs that have different number of members, and that is why I asked the question hahah
If there was a way to get a hidden struct size, it would be a great help to make my code better. Unfortunately, don't have. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, having both `typeX` and `TypeX` but with very different meanings is very confusing. Also, don't hide pointers behind typedefs.

As for your question: No, you cannot recover the size of the object that `t` is pointing to.

`sizeof EXPR` gives you the size of the *type* of EXPR (in bytes). It does not matter what the actual value is (in fact, EXPR isn't even evaluated<sup>1</sup>).

Consider

```
char c;
int i;
double d[100];

TypeX p1 = (TypeX)&c, p2 = (TypeX)&i, p3 = (TypeX)d;
```

All of `p1`, `p2`, `p3` have the same type, so `sizeof` will return the same value for all of them, even though the objects they're pointing to have very different sizes.

Finally, `sizeof (void)` is not a thing in standard C. GCC allows it as an extension (and returns `1`), but it will warn you that this is non-standard if you enable `-pedantic` diagnostics.

<sup>1</sup> - With one relatively obscure exception, which I'm just going to ignore.

Comment: Thank you. I had not thought of it in that way. And I forgot to use -pedantic haha